# How to obtain a collection of records in a table within a function?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a function that takes in a primary key to Patient table. Then for that key if should find all Orders for that patient. Then, from that collection of records it should get the supplies used and their quantities and use the Supplies table to calculate the total cost and return that value.

I am not sure how to get all the orders and how to use them to get the supplies and quantities. I know that I can get them by using a simple select statement but i just do not know how to implement this in a function because it needs to return a value. Does anyone have any advice? I am new to writing code in SQL. I am using MS SQL Server.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
Patient
----------
PatientNo
First,
Last,
Address


OrderTable
----------
OrdNo,
Date,
PatientNo,
Address

OrdLineTable
----------
OrdNo,
SupplyNo,
Quantity


SupplyObject
----------
SupplyNo,
Price
```

Comment: You should `JOIN` the tables, please update your question and post all the tables' structures.

Comment: post schema (or is the question what should the schema be)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if your question is about how to create a function or what the query looks like.  I'll answer the latter.

Let me assume that you have a reasonable data structure with four tables:  `Patients` (which is not used); `Operations` (a list of operations for each patient); `OperationSupplies` (a list of supplies for each operation); and `Supplies` (information about each supply).

```
select coalesce(sum(os.quantity * s.cost), 0) as TotalCost
from Operations o left outer join
     OperationSupplies os
     on os.OperationId = o.OperationId left outer join
     Supplies s
     on s.SupplyId = os.SupplyId
where o.PatientId = @PatientId
```

Here is the structure as a function:

```
create function xxx (@PatientId int)
returns float
as
begin
    declare @val float;

    select @val = coalesce(sum(os.quantity * s.cost), 0) as TotalCost
    from Operations o left outer join
         OperationSupplies os
         on os.OperationId = o.OperationId left outer join
         Supplies s
         on s.SupplyId = os.SupplyId
    where o.PatientId = @PatientId;
    return(@val);
end;
```

Comment: I keep getting an error that says "select statements within a function cannot return data to a client"

Comment: check you have "select @val = coalesce ... " not "select coalesce .." or post your function defintion

Comment: Ya, i fixed that issue. I am trying to test it using this PRINT 'Result A: ' + dbo.fn_BAL('C0954327'); and get the error "Error converting data type varchar to numeric."

Comment: @aaronaaron: You didn't have issues adjusting the table names in this answer to yours, did you? I think changing the type of the parameter should be even more trivial. :)

Comment: Ok i got it. Thank you everyone for your help. @Andriy M i need to follow the orders of the professor Haha